# JavaScript issue in IE with YouTube iFrame API

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube-api

Sorry for the ambiguous title, but this is a strange issue. I'm using the YouTube iFrame API and it works great in all browsers except IE. In IE, none of the JavaScript runs at first. Then, when I open up DevTools and refresh, everything works flawlessly! Anyone, have a clue what could be causing this?

Here is the prototype: http://www.frontendconcepts.com/youtubetest/

Comment: Are you doing anything with the console in your code? In IE, the console doesn't exist until you open the developer tools, so you should actually be getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `console.log(response);` in your ajax call - IE will stop js execution once it hits that line since it doesn't have console until you open up developer tools

```
$.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + userId + '/uploads?&max-results=' + maxResults +'&category=' + tagName + '&alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?', null, function(response) {
  console.log(response); // <-- here
```